# auto load registration form popup on checkout

Tags: magento, popup, checkout

i am working on oncepagecheckout, there is a link "Click here to login or create a new account", However we click on this link a popup of login form does display. but i want to display this login popup form should display automatically on page load, Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with jQuery. Just use below code, this will trigger a click onload of page. Just check the id of the button and replace that in the below code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#your_button_id').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, i already tried this no better luck, i got below message on console, jQuery('#onestepcheckout-login-link').click(); 
Object[a#onestepcheckout-login-link javascript:void(0);] 
My Domain is aradhya15.com, kindly have a look add any products to checkout and check please , Thanks in advance!